# What is the latest kernel in 17.04? 4.10.0-21-generic?

Tags: kernel, kubuntu, 17.04

I am on Kubuntu 17.04. And I wonder - how can I check whether I am on the latest kernel?

I type this in my terminal:

```
$ uname -r
4.10.0-21-generic
```

So is it the latest kernel? If not, how can I update it to the latest one?

Comment: see https://packages.ubuntu.com/

Comment: You can `apt-cache policy linux-generic` to see what version is installed, and what version is available.  Updates are through `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Ukuu (Ubuntu Kernel Update Utility). Check the latest kernel and install.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ukuu
```